# ReactiveX observable that uses another observable

Tags: typescript, angular, reactive-programming

I am trying to write an Angular service that will wrap the regular Http service and automatically make authentication calls if Bearer token is not available or invalid.

Here's an illustration of a regular GET call made via the service:

```
this.httpWithAutomagicAuth
    .get("http://localhost:5001/books")
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
        data => {
            self.data = data;
        }
    );
```

And here's my very sloppy implementation for such service. Obviously, I'm not using the right ReactiveX idioms in the code.

**As you can easily notice I am trying to build an observable (Observable.create) that is using another observable returned by this.login(). I am sure there is a better way of chaining/nesting observable for this scenario.**

Please, suggest improvements that will make code:

- terse
- easy to read and understand

  ```
  @Injectable()
  export class HttpWebApiAuthService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  // ...

  public get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
      // TODO this code is for test purpose only (basically, it required to enforce the jwtToken retrieval branch execution)
      // this.clearJwtToken();

      if (!this.getJwtToken()) {
          return Observable.create(
              (result: Observer<Response>) => {
                  this.login()
                      .map(res => res.json())
                      .subscribe(
                          data => {
                              this.saveJwtToken(data.id_token);

                              this.executeGet(url, options)
                                  .subscribe(authenticationResult => {
                                      result.next(authenticationResult);
                                  });
                          },
                          error => { console.error("Authentication error", error); },
                          () => { console.info("Authentication complete"); }
                      );
                  },
                  error => { console.error("OBSERVABLE error: ", error); },
                  () => { console.info("OBSERVABLE complete");
              }
          );
      } else {
          return this.executeGet(url, options);
      }
  }

  private login() : Observable<Response> {
      const authBody =
          {
              "client_id": "...",
              "username": "...",
              "password": "...",
              // ...
          };
      const headers = new Headers();
      headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

      return this.http.post("https://AUTH_URL", JSON.stringify(authBody), { headers: headers });
  }

  // ...

  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Let's call an Observable which emits a single value a task, usually an async task.
Let's break the flow to smaller tasks:

First, you already have the `login()` task which returns `Observable<Response>`.
Let's extend it to save the jwtToken:

```
let loginAndSaveToken = login().map(res => res.json())
  .do((data: any) => this.saveJwtToken(data.id_token)/*, onError, onComplete if neccessary*/);
```

Now proceed to your `get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs)` function. You need to login and save the token first if you didn't already have a valid token, and then proceed to call http.get, do you? In order to `do this, then that` you need to **concat** the Observables, or use `concatMap`. But if you already have a valid token, you don't have to relogin and just return `http.get`. It is equivalent to `do A, then B` where A is a *dummy* task. I am implementing the dummy task as `Observable.of(1)`

```
public get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response>
{
    return (this.tokenValid() ? Observable.of(1) : loginAndSaveToken)
      .concatMap(x => this.executeGet(url, options));
}
```

Now you have your flow in a cleaner way. It may have some caveats though, for example: 
  If your second `get` call comes before the first one successfully logged in, it will try to login again. It's better to have it waited for the authentication result if one is in progress, especially if your authentication server is configured to deny multiple requests from a specific user in a time window.